# Puedo simplificar codigo HTML + PHP en JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo una pregunta, tengo una web, que usa PHP, hago obtengo unos datos de una web, los almaceno en un array en PHP, y lo muestro directo con la variable en la etiqueta html. Por ejemplo:

```
<h5> <?php echo $spans_name2[$loc]; ?> </h5>
```

Lo muestro asi, y mi idea es esa variable PHP, guardarla en JavaScript, en un archivo .js, para ser mas exacto, y ponerlo en cualquier web, y para mostrarlo mi idea era asi:

```
<h5 id="nombre"></h5>
```

Como para simplificar el codigo, y no tener tantos `<h5> <?php echo $spans_name2[$loc]; ?> </h5>` porque lo muestro en un "for". Gracias, y espero que me entiendan.

Comment: php se ejecuta del lado del servidor.. y js del lado del cliente.. creo que ahi radica tu confusion...

Comment: Ya se eso, por favor, no me trate de un ignorante. No cree que por algo pregunto?

Comment: desconozco, porque la pregunta no parece indicar eso. Y no tuve la intencion de tratarte de ignorante, lamento que lo hayas sentido asi...

Comment: Si no he entendido mal, tienes un array en PHP y quieres "convertirlo" a un array de JS. Cosa que se puede solucionar recorriendo el Array y "montando" el JS, cosa que no es recomendable por temas de seguridad.
¿Podrías mostrar que has intentado con un código simple de ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se considera un peligro de alta seguridad mezclar el **backend** con el **frontend**, para que me entiendas mejor, el **frontend** es todo aquello con lo que el usuario puede ver e interactuar, cosas tales como:

- HTML
- CSS
- Javascript

Esos **3** componentes hacen parte del **frontend**, mientras que el **backend** es todo aquello que la persona no puede ver o interactuar de manera directa, por ejemplo comunicacion entre servidores y bases de datos.

Un ejemplo de lenguajes que se pueden usar del lado del servidor son:

- PHP
- NodeJS (no es un lenguaje, es JS del lado del servidor)
- Perl
- Java
- Python

Y muchos muchos otros, hay muchas opciones en los que respecta al **backend**.

Se considera peligroso y para nada recomendable mezclar el **frontend** con el **backend** debido a que el **backend** deberia estar totalmente aislado y con el menos contacto posible directo del **frontend**.

Esto debido a no solo temas que tienen que ver con la legibilidad del codigo, si no tambien con la seguridad, la organizacion y la acortabilidad de codigo.

Tambien se considera que es buena practica separar el **frontend** del **backend** porque asi siempre tendras aislados las partes que tienen que ver mas que todo con la estructura y lo visual del codigo y las partes que tienen que ver con el servidor.

Esto no te ayudaria solo a ti si no a aquellos futuros programadores con los que posiblemente trabajes en algun proyecto, ellos podran entender mejor la estructura del codigo o codigos que les proporcionas si aislas los lenguajes usados.

Con el porque de que se compromete la seguridad si usas en el mismo archivo tanto:

`HTML`, `CSS`, `Javascript` como `PHP`, puedes pensarlo de la siguiente manera:

Si tu usas por ejemplo un archivo `PHP` para renderizar codigo de una pagina web existe el problema que al ser tu archivo un archivo con extension `.PHP` tu pagina puede simplemente inyectarse con este codigo tan facil como abriendo la consola de tu navegador y digitando una linea.

Eso seria aun mas problematico si en la misma pagina te encargas de la estructura y de hacer operaciones hacia bases de datos.

Sin embargo quiero hacer una distincion importante aqui...

**Si esto es inseguro entonces porque existen frameworks como laravel?, los cuales permiten renderizar en HTML codigo de PHP?**

La respuesta es el como se usan tus recursos y como se separa el **frontend** del **backend** para usarlo en conjunto con **laravel**.

Hay que entender la idea de laravel:

**Que no es laravel y para que no deberia ser usado:**

La idea de **laravel** como `framework` **NO** es la de juntar el **frontend** y el **backend** en un mismo archivo y renderizar los contenidos de `PHP` en `HTML`.

**Para que deberia ser usado laravel:**

La idea de laravel es crear paginas web dinamicas por las cuales los programadores pueden renderizar de manera dinamica cierto contenido que **NO** se extrae al mismo nivel en el que se encuentra la pagina.

Digamos que **laravel** hace las vecez de intermedio entre el **frontend** y el **backend**, donde el **frontend** estaria totalmente separado del **backend**, pero pudiendo en **laravel** renderizar el contenido traido por el backend de manera mas segura.

Esto debido a que como el **frontend** y el **backend** se encuentran separados, aunque se intente inyectar codigo **PHP** este codigo no afectaria de manera directa a los archivos separados del backend, si no mas bien solo al frontend, lo que hace que los archivos importantes por decirlo asi se encuentren mas seguros.

Ahora bien, respecto a tu pregunta, el siguiente codigo:

```
<h5> <?php echo $spans_name2[$loc]; ?> </h5>
```

Si lo usas de tal forma que el backend esta separado (conexiones con servidores, bases de datos y etc), no esta del todo mal y es valido para ser renderizado.

Pero me preocupa aquello que dices mas abajo:

> y mi idea es esa variable `PHP`, guardarla en `JavaScript`, en un
>   archivo `.js`

Recuerda que solo los archivos con extension `.php` tienen el "derecho" o el "potencial" por decirlo de alguna forma de poder ser renderizados mediante `PHP`, por lo tanto aquello que indicas:

**Es imposible.**

Tu unica opcion seria tener tu codigo `javascript` dentro de tu archivo `.php` en el que tienes el `HTML`, pero esto como he dicho antes **NO** es para nada recomendable.

puesto que debemos siempre intentar aislar el frontend del backend y **NO** mezclarlos.

Si bien `laravel` te permite tambien renderizar codigo `PHP` en `javascript`, esto ocurre y **solo puede ocurrir** bajo la misma condición (que el archivo tenga extension `.php`).

Nunca es recomendable mezclar directamente `javascript` con `PHP`, por las limitaciones que hay, por ejemplo, si tienes javascript dentro de un archivo `.php` e intentas pasar una variable de `PHP` a `javascript` se podra hacer, pero esto mismo no se puede a la inversa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. Mi idea era hacer eso para simplificar el codigo que finalmente se imprime en HTML, hacer que imprima todo con una sola etiqueta. Pero si dices que no es recomendable, no lo haré

Comment: De nada amigo @MatiST00 , recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda puedes darla como aceptada ;3